# Create pdf document shortcuts on home screen

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, home-screen-shortcuts

I had downloaded a PDF file. How can I create a shortcut to the PDF document on my home screen. I use Anycut, but it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 5):

[Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro) (free, ad supported) will do what you want.

Once installed, add a shortcut to Astro to your homescreen and it should let you browse to your PDF (or any other file, for that matter).  The shortcut on the homescreen will then take you directly to the file you chose in the file browser.

Comment: But what I expect is, a shortcut direct to the PDF file. Not shortcut to file explorer.

Comment: Yep, give it a go - adding a shortcut to Astro makes Astro popup its explorer, which you can use to find the file you want a shortcut to.  The homescreen shortcut is then to the file you chose, not just Astro.