# Change name of shortcut icon?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, astro-file-manager

I have created a shortcut to a single document. The home page icon carries the name of the file manager (Astro) that I used to create the shortcut (using [the method explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12658/create-pdf-document-shortcuts-on-home-screen)).

I'd like to rename the icon to something more relevant so I can distinguish it from shortcuts to other documents or folders. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Some Launchers (like GO Launcher) let you rename icons on the home screen.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Solution

1. Long press on home screen to activate shortcut launcher
2. Tap on Shortcut
3. Tap on Activites
4. Tap on file manager (Astro)
5. Navigate to file location (internal or external SD card)
6. Tap on target file
7. Accept (or amend) suggested shortcut name > OK
8. Named  shortcut appears on home page under an icon for the associated app to display the document

To open the document, tap on the icon and then tap on the associated app in the menu .

Answer (score 1):

Renaming shortcuts depends on what launcher you use.  For example, with [GO Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex), you simply hold down your finger on whatever you want to rename and a box pops up asking if you want to rename it.
The point being is that each launcher is different, but most are intuitive enough to where you just long click on the icon to rename it.